# Find single element in Kernel of Matrix

Tags: python, scipy, linear-algebra

I want to find a single vector in the Kernel of a Matrix.
What I came up with are the following things:

1. Solve the linear system of equations Ax = 0:

   ```
   dim = np.shape(A)[0]
   v = spl.solve(A, np.zeros(dim))
   return v
   ```

   This  throws an error, because the matrix is obviously not invertible
2. Use singular value decomposition (my TAs suggestion)

```
    U, K, Vt = spl.svd(A)
    return Vt[-1]
```

This is also seems to be the method that [scipy.linalg.null_space](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.null_space.html) uses.

However doing a full singular value decomposition seems like a waste of computational resources, especially since I want to implement Arnoldy Iteration which would be used for big matrices. Is there a better way?